# showing html form values twice at URL

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular JS, bootstrap and some API created in php for my app developement.
Here when I run the app and making it redirect from one page to another page. The Form parameter shows twice at the URL.

like :

```
 http://localhost:8085/TaskManager/Report.html?password=admin&userId=4&type=ADMIN#/Report.html?password=admin&userId=4&type=ADMIN
```

I am holding the parameters in each page (in a form of hidden elements, say 'hiddenForm' with method="get") so that when it's required to redirect another page, these parameters can be available at that page after submitting the 'hiddenForm'. It goes okay every where but only the problem is 
"Showing values twice at URL".

HTML codes : (Dashboard.html)

```
   <form id="hiddenForm">
      <input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="">
      <input id="password" name="password" type="hidden" value="">
      <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="">
    </form>

    <a href="#" onclick="getReports();">Reports</a>
   ......
   ......
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

JS part:(app.js)

```
    /* for getting the parameters form previous page ('Login.html' for this case) and setting them in the current page ('Dashboard.html' for this case)*/
   function getParameterByName(name) {
     name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
     var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
     results = regex.exec(location.search);
     return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
     }         
     var userId='';
     userId = getParameterByName('userId');
     var password='';
     password = getParameterByName('password');         
     var type='';
     type = getParameterByName('type');

     document.getElementById('userId').value=userId;
     document.getElementById('password').value=password;
     document.getElementById('type').value=type;

    function getReports(){           
       document.getElementById('hiddenForm').setAttribute("action","./Report.html");
       document.getElementById('hiddenForm').submit();
      }

     function getDashboard(){           
       document.getElementById('hiddenForm').setAttribute("action","./Dashboard.html");
       document.getElementById('hiddenForm').submit();
      }
```

For redirecting to : (Report.html) /* almost same code... as it needs to hold the previous page's data and can be made available them on submitting to another page */

```
   <form id="hiddenForm">
      <input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="">
      <input id="password" name="password" type="hidden" value="">
      <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="">
    </form>

    <a href="#" onclick="getDashboard();">Dashboard</a>
   ......
   ......
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

Don't know why it's happening so. where I am doing mistake (if any).

I am stuck here, Please suggest me.

Comment: can you please post some codes u used ?

Comment: bring your code in fiddle

Comment: I have edited with the relevant codes. plz check it once.

Comment: @ Kalhano ... could you please help me out.